# laravel show only next and previous link in pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination, laravel-pagination

I ma trying to use Laravel Pagination and I only want to show the Previous and Next link with out the number 1 2 3 ...

how could I do that? I followed Laravel page : 
"Simple Pagination"

If you are only showing "Next" and "Previous" links in your pagination view, you have the option of using the simplePaginate method to perform a more efficient query. This is useful for larger datasets when you do not require the display of exact page numbers on your view:

```
$someUsers = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->simplePaginate(15);
```

but this still shows the page number when I do this in my view:

```
<?php echo $someUsers->links(); ?>
```

can anyone help

Thanks

Comment: All the answers here give you piece of info, however none answers how to do what you ask for **inline** - so check my answer for details.

Comment: if someone looking for how to customize pagination in Laravel 5.3 check out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240777/custom-pagination-view-in-laravel-5/44845954#44845954

Answer (score 16):

**tldr; you want to use `simplePaginate()` method on the query *AND* `links('some.view')` on the paginator (in the view) in order to achieve what you ask for.**

Here's what you need in order to show chosen links in given template:

```
// inline choose simple links (prev, next)
{{ $someUsers->links('pagination::simple') }}

// inline choose slider links
{{ $someUsers->links('pagination::slider') }}

// inline choose slider-3 (default)
{{ $someUsers->links('pagination::slider-3') }}
```

These are framework's templates, placed in laravels directory: `Illuminate/Pagination/views/`

You can always decide to use your custom templates, for this simply call:

```
// assuming you have it in app/views/pagination/my-links.blade.php
{{ $someUsers->links('pagination.my-links') }}

// or using views namespace (you need to define it first)
{{ $someUsers->links('myNamespace::my-links') }}
```

---

Of course you can define your links as default in `app/config/view.php`:

```
// instead of
'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',

// something like
'pagination' => 'pagination.my-links',
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use:

```
$someUsers = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->simplePaginate(15);
```

as you used

and in `app/config/view.php` you need to set `pagination` to `pagination::simple` (by default it's set to `pagination::slider-3`). Then you'll have by default pagination as in the image:

[image: Simple pagination in Laravel]

You can also set custom text for previous and next items editing file `lang/en/pagination.php` (for other language of course you need to change it in other lang directory). By default it's set to:

```
'previous' => '&laquo; Previous',

'next'     => 'Next &raquo;',
```

but you can change it to:

```
'previous' => '&laquo;',

'next'     => '&raquo;',
```

and then it will look like as in the image:

[image: Simple pagination in Laravel - arrows only]

Answer (score 5):

I tried this and it's working with me :

```
{{$someUsers->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')}}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `config/view.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Pagination View
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This view will be used to render the pagination link output, and can
| be easily customized here to show any view you like. A clean view
| compatible with Twitter's Bootstrap is given to you by default.
|
*/

'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',
```

Set this to `simple`.

Source: http://youtu.be/lIEcyOUcNQk?t=8m00s

Comment: will that change all of them or I can still use simplePaginate and paginate() methods?

Comment: Sure you don't have an environment version of this file with different content?

Comment: i changed it to simple now it works , but now all my pagination shows with only previous and next , can i have some with pages and some without pages?

Comment: According to the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) by applying `->simplePaginate(15);` as you have tried. Sure you are not caching the results or updating the wrong line?

Comment: One more thing you should try, clear your `app/storage/view` folder and browser cache.

Comment: it worked now but can I mix it , so sometimes i use with number and others without?

Comment: for me now if I use simplePaginate(15) or paginate(15) they have the same result with Previous and Next link? isnt that suppose to be different?

Comment: You have Previous and Next because of your setting in `view.php`, change that back to `pagination::slider-3`, use `simplePaginate(15)` and clear your `app/storage/view` folder as I suggested.

Comment: yes i did like you said , now my pagination got page number like : 1 2 3 etc and it doesnt really matter if I use simplePaginate(15) or paginate(15) I stil get it with number 1 , 2 3 etc.. , and thats with view.php, go this setting: pagination::slider-3 but thats not what I want I want to use both on different page like one page got numbers of pages otehr got only Previous and Next is that Possible?

Answer (score 2):

See the very bottom of [this manual page](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links) to see how to implement a custom view for the pagination. Summarizing, you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a view for the paginator somewhere in `app/views`.
2. Replace the `pagination` option in `app/config/views.php` with the path Laravel will use to locate your new view.
3. Display your custom paginatation view in your view like this:

   ```
   <?php echo with(new ZurbPresenter($paginator))->render(); ?>
   ```

Where `ZurbPresenter` is the class name of your pagination presenter.

Comment: why do I need a custom pagination , read laravel manual here : http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination under 'Simple Pagination" , why its showing other pages number?