# Custom pagination view in Laravel 5 with appended link

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

As seen here: [Custom pagination view in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240777/custom-pagination-view-in-laravel-5)

```
@include('pagination.default', ['paginator' => $users])
```

replaces the original:

```
$users->render();
```

but how to replace this?

```
 $users->appends(['sortBy' => $sort, 'order' => $order])->render()



@if ($paginator->lastPage() > 1)
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}">Previous</a>
    </li>
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= $paginator->lastPage(); $i++)
        <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $i) ? ' active' : '' }}">
            <a href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
        </li>
    @endfor
    <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $paginator->lastPage()) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1) }}" >Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Durp.

```php
@include('pagination.default', [
    'paginator' => $users->appends([
        'sortBy' => $sort,
        'order' => $order,
    ])
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is:

```
$users->appends(Request::query())->links('Your custom pagination view name');
```

if you want to use custom parameter instead of your all request then just replace

```
'Request::query()' to ['sortBy' => $sort, 'order' => $order].
```