# Laravel 5 Custom Pagination

Tags: pagination, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I created a FoundationFivePresenter by extending the BootstrapThreePresenter and just changing the getDisabledTextWrapper and getActivePageWrapper and placed it in /app/Pagination.

```
namespace App\Pagination;

use Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter;
class FoundationFivePresenter extends BootstrapThreePresenter
{
    /**
     * Get HTML wrapper for disabled text.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDisabledTextWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="unavailable"><span>'.$text.'</span></li>';
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML wrapper for active text.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getActivePageWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="current"><span>'.$text.'</span></li>';
    }
}
```

I found where the presenter is set:

```
public function render(Presenter $presenter = null)
{
    if (is_null($presenter) && static::$presenterResolver) {
        $presenter = call_user_func(static::$presenterResolver, $this);
    }

    $presenter = $presenter ?: new BootstrapThreePresenter($this);

    return $presenter->render();
}
```

But I didn't want to instantiate my presenter and pass it to render in the view. So I looked at LengthAwarePaginator, since in my controller I'm calling User::paginate(15) and not using the SimplePaginator, and the only other way to set $presenterResolver seems to be by extending LengthAwarePaginator and setting it to default to a new instance of FoundationFivePresenter in render, or somehow instantiating LengthAwarePaginator and calling presenter passing in a new instance of my presenter which seems even more cumbersome.

Is there an easier way to use a custom paginator in Laravel 5.1 that doesn't involve passing in an instance in a view? I checked the config files for a setting just in case.

Comment: Here is the post for Laravel 5.8 about how to extend core pagination: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58005778/1916821