# ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81: Method lastPage does not exist. ---- laravel 5.2

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

Trying to achiveve the pagination of my user list (working fine), but on my filter page ( http://wasamar.dev/admin@users@filter?filter=new ) it give me this error,

```
ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method lastPage does not exist. (View: C:\laragon\www\wasamar\resources\views\pagination\limit_links.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\wasamar\resources\views\pagination\limit_links.blade.php)
```

This is the paginator render

```
@include('pagination.limit_links', ['paginator' => $newestUsers])
```

**THE CUSTOM PAGINATION VIEW**

```
<!-- 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240777/custom-pagination-view-in-laravel-5
    Author: Mantas D
 -->
<?php
// config
$link_limit = 7; // maximum number of links (a little bit inaccurate, but will be ok for now)
?>

@if ($paginator->lastPage() > 1)
<div class="pagination-centered">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="montserrat-font {{ ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) ? ' unavailable' : '' }}">
            <a href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}">First</a>
        </li>
        @for ($i = 1; $i <= $paginator->lastPage(); $i++)
        <?php
        $half_total_links = floor($link_limit / 2);
        $from = $paginator->currentPage() - $half_total_links;
        $to = $paginator->currentPage() + $half_total_links;
        if ($paginator->currentPage() < $half_total_links) {
         $to += $half_total_links - $paginator->currentPage();
         }
         if ($paginator->lastPage() - $paginator->currentPage() < $half_total_links) {
            $from -= $half_total_links - ($paginator->lastPage() - $paginator->currentPage()) - 1;
        }
        ?>
        @if ($from < $i && $i < $to)
        <li class="montserrat-font {{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $i) ? ' current' : '' }}">
            <a href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
        </li>
        @endif
        @endfor
    <li class="montserrat-font {{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $paginator->lastPage()) ? ' unavailable' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->lastPage()) }}">Last</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
@endif
```

based on this ( [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240777/custom-pagination-view-in-laravel-5) Author: Mantas D ) Then i tried this 
`{{ $newestUsers->links() }}` and i got this error too.

```
ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method links does not exist. (View: C:\laragon\www\wasamar\resources\views\main_app\admin\users@filter.blade.php)
```

so what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was easy: I had forgotten to add the `paginate(30)` method to the Users model.  Adding that will solve the problem.