# How can I display pagination in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.6

I use laravel 5.6

I try this documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

My controller like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $products = $this->product->list(); 
    dd($products);
    return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
}
```

My list function like this :

```
public function scopeList($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
}
```

If I `dd($products);`, the result like this :

[image]

On the view laravel, I add this :

```
 {{ $products->links() }}
```

Then I check on the web, the result empty

Why the result empty?

Is there something wrong?

If the image not display, access here : https://postimg.org/image/w39usbfrv/

Comment: is *list()* function exist?

Comment: @arunkumar Yes. I had update my question

Comment: try changing `{{ $products->links() }}` to `{!! $products->render() !!}` as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Option It's the same. The result is empty

Comment: Are you running a foreach statement? Share the view file code.

Comment: add more products

Answer (score 7):

your controller code will look like this

```
$products = DB::table('products')->paginate(20);
return view('admin.product.index', ['products' => $products ]);
```

your view page code look like this

```
   @foreach ($products as $product)
         {{ $product->product_name}}
    @endforeach
    {{ $products->links() }}
```

Note : Add more items more than your limit to view pagination links

Answer (score 4):

In laravel pagination can be done using two method

**1) Using Query Builder Results**

```
$products= DB::table('products')->paginate(15);
```

or

```
$products= DB::table('products')->simplePaginate(15);
```

If you only need to display simple "Next" and "Previous" links in your pagination view, you may use the simplePaginate method.

**2) Using Eloquent Results**

```
$products= App\Products::paginate(15);
```

**To print pagination links**

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

**customize pagination view using**

```
{{ $paginator->links('view.name') }}
```

or you can refer this link for more custom pagination view

[Custom pagination view in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240777/custom-pagination-view-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Is it possible to display the first page?

Answer (score 1):

Use `paginate()` function

```
App\Product::paginate();
```

or by query builder:

```
$products= DB::table('products')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: I had it in method list. See my question. I had update it

Comment: forget  `$this->product->list();` do as my answer

Answer (score 1):

That's because, you are paginiating for 20 products and you have only 11 products. That is why
pagination will only come only if there are more then the number of products you are requesting .. For you u have one page and 11 products. Look at the top `#total:11` , `lastpage:1` that's why empty pagination , because there is nothing to paginate.