# Paginate not showing all data

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

My paginate function is not working correctly for one set of data. The data is just disappearing after the set number of paginate. When I go to the correct url and enter page 2 it will appear but not giving me the option of switching pages at the bottom of the web page like it should.

I have used the same good from the one I have working but it does not seem to do the job.

```
    $vulnerabilitys = Vulnerability::orderBy('risk', 'asc')->paginate(6);
    return view('vulnerabilities.index')>with('vulnerabilitys',$vulnerabilitys);
```

I expect the result to give me the option to change to the next page at the bottom of the data, by having a page 1/2/3 etc.

Comment: Have you add this code in in your view file `{{ $vulnerabilitys->links() }` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display pagination in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903173/how-can-i-display-pagination-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `{{ $vulnerabilitys->links() }}` to your view?

See [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Comment: This returns the error: Call to undefined method App\Vulnerability::links()

Comment: How does your code looks like? Show the foreach loop and how you implemented $vulnerabilitys->links()

Comment: foreach ($vulnerabilitys as $vulnerabilitys)
        <div class = "well">
            <h3><a href="/vulnerabilities/{{$vulnerabilitys->id}}">{{$vulnerabilitys->risk}}</a></h3>
            <small>{{$vulnerabilitys->description}}</small>
        </div>       
    @endforeach
    {{$vulnerabilitys->links()}}

Comment: You should use something like foreach ($vulnerabilitys as $vulnerability) and change everything in the loop from $vulnerabilitys to $vulnerability. Check the link i provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

`@if(count($vulnerabilitys)>0)
    @foreach ($vulnerabilitys as $vulnerability)
        <div class = "well">
            <h3><a href="/vulnerabilities/{{$vulnerability->id}}">{{$vulnerability->risk}}</a></h3>
            <small>{{$vulnerability->description}}</small>
       </div>
    @endforeach
    {{$vulnerabilitys->links()}}`