# How to paginate the laravel collection using relationships?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 7 and in my controller I want to paginate data,
here is my code

```
$offers = Auth::user()->products()->paginate(1)->with('offers')->get()->pluck('offers')->flatten();
```

The question is, how can i use

```
$offers->links()
```

in my blade.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display pagination in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903173/how-can-i-display-pagination-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one: [Paginated Collections in Laravel](https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e)