# changing pagination arrow in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have added pagination in controller and included in view page.

```
$query=$query->pagination(10);
   return view('layouts.home',['users'=>$query]); 
    {{$users->links()}}
```

This pagination shows as `<< 1 2 >>`

I want to change `<<` to `<` and `>>` to `>`.
How can I change the arrow in laravel 5.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom pagination view in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240777/custom-pagination-view-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Get the URL by these function and setup with your own formatting: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This will generate the pagination view files that are used to display the pagination. You can then edit them.

This command will place the views in the resources/views/vendor/pagination directory. The bootstrap-4.blade.php file within this directory corresponds to the default pagination view. You may edit this file to modify the pagination HTML.

Comment: how to check which pagination file is used for pagination I have bootstrap-4.blade.php,simple-bootstrap-4.blade.php ,default.blade

Comment: bootstrap-4.blade.php is the default view. Kindly accept this as the answer if this satisfies your needs, thank you.

Comment: If you still use bootstrap-3, add this line in the AppServiceProvider boot() methode: ´Paginator::useBootstrapThree();´

Comment: using bootstrap-4