# How to use a custom pagination laravel?

Tags: laravel

At the moment I already have the basic bootstrap pagination, but I want to customize this. Customizing this in the the `bootstrap-4.blade.php` in the vendor file itself only limits since you can't change the .active button which will always be blue.

Is there a way to make a custom pagination for laravel?

at the moment I just use `{{$servers->links()}}`

Comment: The `$servers` variable you have should have a bunch of methods available that you can use to construct the links (first, previous, page, next, last). See the available methods here: https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html, and see if you can construct a button using them. That would be a good starting point :)

Comment: Not that I've seen, and asking for tutorials is considered off-topic for Stackoverflow. There's at least one other question that has been asked here that might help though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240777/custom-pagination-view-in-laravel-5.